# Elasticsearch index a document

Tags: java, android, rest, post, elasticsearch

I'm having serious issues trying to find the correct syntax to push a document into an elasticsearch index by type.

My code im using to do this is :

```
String url = "https://my_url/my_index_name";

StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("form");
                String site = jsonResponse.getString("site"),
                        network = jsonResponse.getString("network");
                Log.d("Site: ", site + "\nNetwork: "+network);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("JSON EXCEPTION", e.toString());
            }
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`)`

```
{
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams()
{
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    // the POST parameters:
    params.put("type", "type_name");;
    params.put("field1", field1_value);
    params.put("field2", field2_value);
    params.put("field3", field3_value);
    params.put("field4", field4_value);
    params.put("field5", field5_value);
    return params;
}
};

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);
```

It's hitting the server, as I'm getting 400 requests, but I just cant get it to go in using this.

```
12-14 16:19:04.533  12642-13089/? E/Volley﹕ [41831]
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for URL
```

Can some enlighten me as to what the correct syntax is, using java code, or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I assumed the correct syntax was:

http:// url | index_name | type | body ?

EDIT: I've searched SO, elastic java api's, google groups and all over the internet for 3 days now, with no luck! Anything at all is greatly appreciated !

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("VOLLEY ERROR", "" + error.toString());
                }
            }
```

Results in : VOLLEY ERROR﹕ com.android.volley.ServerError

Any ideas?

Comment: 400 is a "bad request" response code, you need to find the exact error-message in the response that comes back with this code. That error message (it is there somewhere, check the logs) will tell you exactly what part of your requests elasticsearch did not understand

Comment: Any idea how I can do this? I've successfully queried the index and retrieved mappings in logcat.

Comment: maybe in the exception-handler error.getMessage() ? The VolleyError should provide access to the complete error-message.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that one, ok ill check thanks.

Comment: ok that didn't turn up anything, I've made an edit there.

Comment: Elasticsearch itself might log that error? Can you access the log files on the elasticsearch server?

Comment: You definitely have ES set up to use https?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to fix it.

There was two issues:

The first issue was with the URL which was:

```
String url = "https://my_url/my_index_name";
```

It should have been:

```
String url = "https://my_url/my_index_name/type%20-d";
```

The second issue was with the actual arguments:

```
params.put("type", "type_name");;
params.put("field1", field1_value);
params.put("field2", field2_value);
params.put("field3", field3_value);
params.put("field4", field4_value);
params.put("field5", field5_value);
return params;
```

I swapped this out for :

```
String urlParameters =
                "{" +
                "        \"field\": \" + field_value \"," +
                "        \"field\": \" + field_value \"," +
                "        \"field\": \" + field_value \"," +
                "        \"field\": \" + field_value \"," +
                "        \"field\": \" + field_value \"" +
                 "}";
```

And post by:

```
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
```

Everything is working as I want now, thanks for the help.